# Problem with Displaying Procces in Components filed in Module Descriptors

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I generated one proces with robocod.jar with requiments who are written in xml..then i change some default activities from older project  in one sub procces.

Actualy this project has three procceses(one of them is subprocces)..but when i go to Components and trying to add them one of them is disappearing..i didn't touch other two proccess but still one of them i can't store in components ..please can anyone help me how can i solve this?

When i click  "Create or Add a Component Procces" in the right corner in the 'Component Configurations' the Procceses are here,then i click every singel Procces and the i'm clicking ok..and after saving the project one procces is disappearing..i check every activity anda shared resources and everything seems to be allright except this.

[image]

Comment: The process which is disappearing, is the subprocess?

Comment: Actualy in the ModuleDescriptors/Components it can be veiwed only main procceses but i already fixed this issue...i just copy that procces who was disappearing and paste in the same package and copy of that procces is apearing regular in the Commponents,and delete the old procces .